# Is there any practical difference between しばらく and しばらくの間?

Tags: word-choice, usage, adverbs, word-usage

While answering [How does しばらく work with ていない?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28147/how-does-%E3%81%97%E3%81%B0%E3%82%89%E3%81%8F-work-with-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)  I started to wonder if 暫く{しばらく} and 暫く{しばらく}の間{あいだ} were fully interchangeable? Or are there any examples where you would use one and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, しばらく is 'a while'. When it is used alone, it usually means 'for a while'. When other words come after しばらく、the meaning change:

> しばらく前 : a while back
>   しばらくして : after a while
>   しばらくぶり : (something reoccurs) after a while
>   しばらくの間 : for a while (makes it clear that the しばらく means 'for a while')