# Meaning of 寝てない

Tags: grammar

> 昨日｛きのう｝も全然｛ぜんぜん｝**寝｛ね｝てない**。*
>
> Yesterday I didn't sleep at all.

Is it 寝る　in て-form followed by ある in negative form? Or a contraction of 寝ていない?

Also, why is it not in past form? I thought one should say:

> 寝ていなかった.

*よつばと！Vol. 2 #11 p.7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

寝てない is a very common contraction of 寝ていない, where there is a [subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18965/5010) いる. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010). To clarify, the simple nai-form of 寝る is 寝ない, since 寝る is a vowel-stem (aka ichidan) verb.

いる in this case is analogous to English *present perfect aspect* (eg, "have slept"), which describes the continuation of some state (in your sentence, sleeplessness). See the discussion in this question: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

You would probably say to someone who just woke up, using the past tense:

> よく寝た? Did you sleep well?

But when you see someone who looks sleepy at work, something like this is more likely to be heard:

> 昨日あまり寝てないの? Haven't you slept well last night?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it's describing a state that continues to the present (like present perfect in Enlish).

or possibly a habit or condition that generally exists ("aspect").

To describe a condition that existed last week, one would say : 寝ていなかった

---

The exact same question here:  http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/9196348.html

> 昨日寝てない？ (これはドラマからの台詞です。) . . . なぜ「昨日寝てなかった？」ではないのですか?
>
> 自分のことなら、「昨日寝てない」というのは普通の言い方です。
>
> (Past perfect?)  --  ㋔過去に完了した動作を表す。 「少年使節一行はローマ教皇にも会っている」 「君はよく勉強しているなあ」

---

「君はよく勉強しているなあ」 . . . This last example is very helpful.

To say I'm not prepared (have not well prepared) for the test today,  I can say

「よく勉強してない」 　　  or　　   「昨日 勉強してない」  　　 or　　   「今日のテスト、勉強してない」

Sleeping is a kind of preparation.

---

To sum up . . .

For 「昨日 寝てない」 there are a few different possible interpretations.

1. present perfect　　 「昨日から 寝てない」
2. general condition, habit　　 「最近 よく寝てない」
3. (past perfect?) or Experience

   3a.  　Preparation, e.g. for a test.

「よく寝てない」 　　  or　　   「昨日 寝てない」  　　 or　　   「今日テストがあるのに、寝てない」

---

I'm still not sure if i understand Joe's comment (below) fully.

> http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/170812/meaning/m0u/
>
> ねる【寝る／×寐る】  .........
>
> １ 眠りにつく。寝床に入る。睡眠をとる。眠る。「ぐっすりねた」「ねる間も惜しんで働く」
>
> ２ 病気で床につく。寝込む。「風邪で二、三日ねていた」
>
> ３ からだを横たえる。また、そのような状態で休む。「ねながら本を読む」「大の字にねる」 ................

So 寝る means both "to sleep" 睡眠をとる。 and "to fall asleep" 眠りにつく。

> 「寝る」と「眠る」の違い | 違いがわかる事典
>
> chigai-allguide.com/寝ると眠る/
>
> 寝るは眠りにつくことを意味し、寝るも眠るも「睡眠」を表す言葉であるが、「立ったまま寝てしまった」というのは間違いで、「立ったまま眠ってしまった」というのが正しい。 寝ると眠るの違いは何かといえば、重点の置かれるポイントで、対義語と合わせて考えると ...

「立ったまま寝てしまった」 is perfectly fine, as in this example :

<sub>detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp › › 健康、病気、病院 --- 電車の中で立ったまま寝てしまった時に、窓ガラスやドアにガツン！とぶつけたり、つり革につかまったまま前に倒れそうになり危なかった覚えがありますが、本当に倒れてしまった方いますか？</sub>

Comment: It seems to depend on your definition of 寝る. English dictionaries have it as "sleep" while Japanese dictionaries have it as "眠りにつく" or "fall asleep." Actual usage seems to vary between both. For example, 長く寝た only makes sense if you use the English definition.