# Why 来ています rather than 来ました

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect

This is the first sentence of an NHK article published today (September 2, 2016) discussing the high number of typhoons in waters near Japan.

> 気象庁によると、ことし６月から８月までに７つの台風が日本の近くに来ています。
>
> According to the Japanese Meteorological Agency, this year between June and August, 7 typhoons approached Japan. (I omitted near because I think approach implies it).

I'm wondering why the article chose to use **来ています** to describe what the article itself implies is a **past action**.

I understand that the ～ている form describes continued state when used with momentary verbs like 来る.  However, I don't see why a typhoon approaching is considered a continued state since the typhoon is currently not still there. I would have assumed it should be either a completed past action or a completed past state that is not currently continuing.

**My question explicitly is, could someone possibly contrast the meanings of the above sentence if 来ました or 来ていました had been used instead?**

Full article: http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010664611000/k10010664611000.html

Thanks

Comment: Of interest: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/%E5%A4%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%8B%E7%8C%AB-vs-%E5%A4%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E7%8C%AB/3364#3364

Comment: For more, look た vs ている on this Q&A, that may prove very informative.

Comment: This link might be useful http://www.guidetojapanese.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6734

Comment: According to "A Dictionary of Intermediate Grammar", page 35 and page 37: 
"Usually a series of past events are narrated in the past tenses. But primarily in written Japanese discourse that narrates a past event, past tenses often switch to nonpast tenses. "
"The use of such nonpast tenses has an effect of creating a vivid sense of immediateness to the reader ".
So  the article could have said :
７つの台風が日本の近くに来ました。
but 来ています is more dramatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 「昨日 寝てない」 there are a few different possible interpretations.

1. present perfect　　 「昨日から 寝てない」
2. general condition, habit　　 「最近 よく寝てない」
3. (past perfect?) or Experience

   3a.  　Preparation, e.g. for a test. 　　--------------- 　　See:  [Meaning of 寝てない](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/38796/meaning-of-%e5%af%9d%e3%81%a6%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84/38807#38807)

---

> 気象庁によると、ことし６月から８月までに７つの台風が日本の近くに来ています。

This has (mostly) elements of  [ present perfect ] (... so far, there have been ...)

and possibly [ general condition, habit ]

> My question explicitly is, could someone possibly contrast the meanings of the above sentence if 来ました or 来ていました had been used instead?

- 気象庁によると、ことし６月から８月までに７つの台風が日本の近くに来ました。 <----- This is just a statement of fact.  Semantically, very flat.
- 気象庁によると、ことし６月から８月までに７つの台風が日本の近くに来ています。 <----- This suggests that we are psychologically engaged / invested in this information.  -- that we don't want another big one to hit us (soon).
- 気象庁によると、ことし６月から８月までに７つの台風が日本の近くに来ていました。 <----- This is much less suspenseful.  The assumption is ...  [ We had 7 of them, but the 8th one is not expected any time soon. ]

Comment: `that we don't want another big one to hit us (soon).` -> No it doesn't imply that. The sentence is used in a context like "So far we had 7, and there's possibility that we'll have more. / So far we have had 7, and we may or may not have more." `We had 7 of them, but the 8th one is not expected any time soon.` ->  No it doesn't imply that. It's used in a context like "We had 7 from Jun to Aug, (now it's Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec,) and we didn't have any more after Aug. / and we had 1/2/3... more after Aug." きています is more like "So far we have had", like present perfect tense, and

Comment: (cont.) きていました is more like "We had had~~ (and after that we had...)", like past perfect tense.