# perfective aspect vs resultative present progressive vs resultative past progressive

Tags: conjugations, tense, aspect

Firstly, I am not a linguist and will probably use linguistic terminology inappropriately. よろしくお願いします。

> What is the difference in meaning between verbs in the perfective aspect (～た), present progressive (～ている), and past progressive (～ていた), *specifically verbs
>   that denote a **resultative** meaning?*
>
> Alternatively, what is the difference in meaning between 死んだ{しんだ}、死んでいる、and
>   死んでいた, and between 来た{きた}、来ている、and 来ていた?

Take the verb 死ぬ (and pretend resurrection is possible).

1. In the perfective aspect, which denotes a completed (perfected)
   action, 死んだ translates simply to "[subject/topic] died, *and may or
   may not still be dead presently*", or more simply "died".
2. In the (resultative) present progressive, the deadness is still
   imperfectively ongoing, thus 死んでいる translates to "[subject/topic]
   died, *and is still dead presently*", or more simply "is dead".
3. In the (resultative) past progressive, 死んでいた means "[subject/topic]
   died, *and was still dead at the time in reference, though may or
   may not still be dead presently*," or maybe "[subject/topic] *was*
   dead, *though may or may not still be dead presently*." More simply "was
   dead". These attempted understandings almost sound like trying to force the perfect tense in English onto the perfective resultative
   past progressive meaning in Japanese. How can this error in understanding be rectified?

Please explain the semantic and pragmatic differences between the three forms of the above two verbs (死ぬ、来る), specifically *comparing and contrasting the Japanese meanings to the English meanings with linguistic/grammatical evidence supporting said explanations, taking into account the communicative limitations resulting from the fundamental differences in how verbs are positioned relatively in time between the two languages.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/when-is-v%e3%81%a6%e3%81%84%e3%82%8b-the-continuation-of-action-and-when-is-it-the-continuation-of-state)

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57193/5010 But if you already understand these and want more authoritative references, please say so.