# Japanese Past Progressive?

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax, て-form, tense

《アパート『へ』帰る『と』ハガキ『が』一枚届いていた…》

In that sentence, why is the verb using the past progressive form?
届いていた=〜て+いた right? Does it mean that the letter was being delivered when he got to this apartment?

Source: [ブラックジャックによろしく](https://www.sukima.me/bv/t/blackjackniyoroshiku/v/1/s/3/p/10)

Comment: Please see the answer in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57195/5010), too.