# Why「なっていた」is used here?

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect, past

I was reading a manga about a boy who turned into a girl. I found this odd line.

> つまり... 目が覚めたら突然女の子になっていた... という事でいいですか?

When the girl-boy arrived at school, his kouhai didn't recognize him at first. After he explained to him everything, the junior was shocked and said the line above.

1. Why「なっていた」is used here? He became a girl and he hasn't transformed back to a boy yet. It is supposed to be「なっている」based on my understanding. Is it an error?
2. What「...でいいですか」means? My intuition tells me it means "...is it true"? Did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> つまり... 目が覚めたら突然女の子になっていた... という事でいいですか?

- In other words... when you woke up you had become a girl... is that correct?

> Why「なっていた」is used here? He became a girl and he hasn't transformed back to a boy yet. It is supposed to be「なっている」based on my understanding. Is it an error?

- They are talking about a experience that happened in the past, if you use 「なっている」here it would sound like "When you woke you are a girl" / "When I woke up I am a girl", it would sound off. Just cause you say you "had become" it does not imply you are no more.

> What「...でいいですか」means? My intuition tells me it means "...is it true"? Did I understand it correctly?

- 「ということ」roughly translates to "the thing you said", "so that means".
  in a more literal translation it would mean "Is it ok to go by ... (this version of the story)"

Comment: I see. What if he uses なった instead of なっていた? Will the meaning change?

Comment: I think it would mean "When I woke up I was a girl", it is hard to explain, but for me なっていた feels like "reliving the experience" while なった just states the fact.

Comment: @JimmyYang If なった was used instead, the meaning would be: "you became a girl _after_ you woke up" (or simply "when you woke up you became a girl" without "had"); just like 目が覚めたらコーヒーを飲んだ means "I drank coffee after I wake up". 目が覚めたらコーヒーを飲んでいた on the other hand would be fucking weird: "When I woke up, I was drinking coffee"?!

Comment: @JimmyYang なった means waking up and becoming a girl happened at the same time (in other words, it sounds like "I became a girl because I woke up"). なっ[ていた](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57195/5010) means the transformation had happened while (s)he was sleeping.