# Is 茂る a stative verb?

Tags: verbs

Why don't dictionaries include this kind of things? Do Japanese ones do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

茂る is a punctual (instant state-change) verb (aka 瞬間動詞). That is, この森には様々な木が茂っている almost certainly means that the forest is full of (already-grown) various trees, not that various trees are in the process of growing now.

> Why don't dictionaries include this kind of things?

Unlike the verb conjugation patterns (godan, ichidan, etc.), the differences between action/stative/punctual are often blurry, and it's almost impossible to perfectly categorize them. See discussions about [溶けている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3140/5010) and [寝ている](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57195/5010).

> Do Japanese ones do?

Unfortunately, no.